# Import Swift Pod into ObjC Pod

Tags: ios, swift

So I've found many answer online that explain how to use Swift pod in an ObjC XCode Project, but none explaining what was the procedure for importing Swift Pod file into a ObjC pod...

I can't just do this:

`In Build Settings, under Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name, you should use common name for every target, for example MyProject-Swift.h.`

Since from my pod there is only the Podspec to play with and the bridging header...

I'm talking about the import at the top of a file like this: (but it doesnt compile in ObjC)

```
#import "MyTimer.swift"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `spec.dependency` is not what you want?

Comment: @KirilS. No what I mean is the import at the top of the file -> #import "IpnosTimer.h"  but a Swift file from another pod

Comment: So sounds like it has nothing to do with podspec then: podspec is only used for distributing _your_ pod after you can build it. But if you want to import into your project, so you can build your project, so you are talking either about adding it to `podfile`, or whatever other building tool you are using, or even statically into the project.

Comment: @KirilS. I realize my question wasnt clear... I have a pod_A written in Swift, and in the podspec of my Pod_B (this one written in ObjC), I import Pod_A like this ->   `s.dependency 'Pod_A'` , but then I can't use `#import "MyTimer.swift"` in my ObjC file because it's a swift file from Pod_A...